# Routing between domain.com/root/featureA and domain.com/root/featureB

Tags: angular

For a few technical reasons, I have a small angular (cli v6) based project which is hosted in a subdirectory under the webhost root (something that has been working fine with the --base-href parameter when using `npm run build`.)

However, I am running into some difficulties in arranging the routes to support this.  The `bootstrap: []`'d component loads and functions without issue.  However, entering the path to "featureB" directly only yields the bootstrapped component ("featureA").

Before bothering with posting code, it seemed worthwhile to first find out if this is just simply a design that is not intended/supported by Angular.   I admit I am unsure as to how a hosted webserver would know to first serve up the Angular app in "`/root/*`", when the request is for "`/root/featureB`", and then render the featured component and route.

Must these two features then be developed and deployed separately in order to facilitate the two routes?

I considered using the # syntax (thinking the system would then grab the full app from the route and then perhaps determine which route/component to load based on the hash path)... is that the only solution aside from creating a separate project for each?

Eg: www.domain.com/root/#featureA and then www.domain.com/root/#featureB (whereby the full angular project would be loaded by the `/root/` request and could then load the appropriate route)

### EDIT 1

With `enableTracing: true`, I see the following (which is odd because it is recognizing the correct routes, but not loading the corresponding components)

You can see the lengthy log output [here](https://pastebin.com/eZ10rFf0)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { MyService } from './services/my.service';

import { MyUploadComponent } from './my-upload/my-upload.component';
import { MyEditComponent } from './my-editor/my-editor.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyUploadComponent,
    MyEditComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ MyService ],
  bootstrap: [ MyUploadComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MyUploadComponent } from './my-upload/my-upload.component';
import { MyEditComponent } from './my-editor/my-editor.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'my-upload' },
  { path: 'my-upload', component: MyUploadComponent, },
  { path: 'my-editor', component: MyEditComponent, },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### EDIT 2

When using `<router-outlet>` in the `index.html` shell, is `<app-root>` (and a component `selector`) still needed/used?  My understanding is that router-outlet is instead where the output from routing is to be placed (which is the purpose of the `<app-root>` tag I believe.)  Removing `<app-root>` and the associated `selector` from the components only made things worse.

### EDIT 3

I tried the following in my `index.html` just for testing and it appears that, in spite of the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#routeroutlet) which state, "Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state", I somehow still do not fully understand the workings/purpose of `router-outlet` (despite a number of tutorials and videos which made use of it.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root><h1>Loading...</h1></app-root>
  <router-outlet><h1>Routing...</h1></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<h1>Routing...</h1>` (`h1` just used to improve visibility) remains regardless of url entered.

I thought perhaps that, when I enter a url directly into the browser address bar, it was going back to the server to request all the resources again (effectively reloading the app, which would explain why it remains at the `bootstrap`'d component interface and never loaded the other.)  However, that does not appear the case (as I expected initially.)  Devtools show no traffic/requests.

### Edit 4

I found [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/location-service/), which seemed to make a far more reasonable suggestion (and also appeared to be more current, 4/2017).  I added the following to my **routing.module.ts**'s `@NgModule` section...

```
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ]
```

But this resulted in no change to the behavior (resulted in the same trace info logged.)

### Edit 5

[Repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-probs-ng6)

Answer (score 0):

The answer now seems (relatively) obvious (as I feared ;-) )

The critical bits...

`index.html` needs (just) the simple `<app-root></app-root>` section.

`app.module.ts` needs a basic `AppComponent` to load as the `bootstrap`'d component...

```
import { NgModule, } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  // NEW!
import { AppRoutingModule } from './routing';

import { MyUploadComponent } from './my-upload/my-upload.component';
import { MyEditComponent } from './my-edit/my-edit.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,  // NEW!
    MyUploadComponent,
    MyEditComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  // Common module, ngIf, ngFor, etc
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]  // CHANGED!
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.component.ts` needs just a basic shell that points to the root `<app-root>`, and then offers a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that route output is loaded into...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

(Now) working [repro here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-probs-ng6).